# import one component from module to component of another module

Tags: angular, module

I work with angular 6 and i have a `media` module. I want to import `MediaComponent` ( exported in `MediaModule`) but i have this error:

```
media.module"' has no exported member 'MediaComponent'.
```

this is the MediaModule declaration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MediaRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, MediaComponent],
  exports: [
    MediaComponent,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
```

and this is another module declaration:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    EM,
    EditorRoutingModule,
    MediaModule
  ],
  declarations: [ListComponent, CreateComponent, AddimageComponent]
})
```

from component in another module (`EditorModule`), this is my import:

```
import { MediaComponent } from '@app/views/media/media.module';
```

and i got the exception.

**Notice:** When i use `media directive` in a component on `EditorModule`, it work file. for example
`<app-media></app-media>` display the content of `MediaComponent`

Comment: no need to import it again you imported it's module and it's enough.

Comment: I want to create dialog box with the content of this component. So i need to import it. see https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples

Comment: see this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-dialog-4vms1u) and how it's using example module.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot the `export` keyword when declaring your module?

Comment: @David not, i'm not forget the export keyboard

Comment: @fatemefazli you imported the component located in same module. I want to import component declared in another module.

Comment: Import the component from where it is exported (from TS perspective), that is to say the component `import { MediaComponent } from '@app/views/media/media.component';` Do not import it from the module

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make sure `media.module.ts` exports a the `MediaComponent` class.

`export { MediaComponent } from 'path/to/media.component';`

Answer (score 6):

You need to export the MediaComponent from the MediaModule in both the Angular sense and in the JavaScript sense, which are different things.

You have already exported the component in the Angular sense by including it the 'exports' section of the module's @NgModule decorator, but you also need to add `export {MediaComponent}` at the end of the module file so that your `import { MediaComponent } from '@app/views/media/media.module';` will work.

Also, you should not be exporting another module from your module - you should remove 'CommonModule' from the MediaModule's 'exports' section.

So, change

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MediaRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, MediaComponent],
  exports: [
    MediaComponent,
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export class MediaModule {
}
```

to:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MediaRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  declarations: [LayoutComponent, MediaComponent],
  exports: [
    MediaComponent
  ]
})
export class MediaModule {
}

export {MediaComponent};
```